# Thymeleaf - Spring Boot MVC resource location based on profile

Tags: javascript, css, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How can I load static js and css on development profile, but from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com on production profile? Using Spring Boot - MVC and Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to configure or provide your own `ResourceHandlerRegistry`.
Then you can define where spring-boot looks for static resources.

You can look [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot)

You can use properties based on your active profiles so that you can load resources in different stages from different locations